# Pullout PHP date and Time Separately

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
<?php echo DPCalendarHelper::getDateStringFromEvent($event, $params->get('event_date_format', 'm.d.Y'), $params->get('event_time_format', 'g:i a'));?>
```

I want to be able to add a "span" to both the event_date_format and the event_time_format. How would I modify the code above to add the tags?

Currently the output is like this "Friday September 09, 2016 7:00 pm - 8:00 pm"

I want to be able to add a div or span around the time and date separately. Like the following:

```
<div>Friday September 09, 2016 <span>7:00 pm - 8:00pm</span></div>
```

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: Currently ,what is output of above code?

Comment: I edited the post above. to what I want to achieve.

Comment: format the date using that `DPCalendarHelper` whatever that is, then instead of constructing the format outright, output it piece by piece including the html markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you should use substr function of php

Example here:

```
  $time_str = 'Friday September 09, 2016 7:00 pm - 8:00 pm';
  $comma_pos = strpos($time_str, ',');
  $date = substr($time_str, 0, $comma_pos + 7);
  $time = substr($time_str, $comma_pos + 7, strlen($time_str));
  $result = '<div>' . $date . '<span>' . $time . '</span></div>';
  echo $result;
```

I think it work !

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="Friday September 09, 2016 7:00 pm - 8:00 pm";
$str_date= explode("-",$str);

$date=strtotime($str_date[0]);
$result = '<div>' . date("l F j, Y ",trim($date)) . '<span>' . date("h:i A",trim($date))." - ".$str_date[1] . '</span></div>';
echo $result;
```